# Recursive Models of dynamic linear economics (Hansen / Sargent, 2014) - optimal linear regulator problem / solution of bellman equation p. 34 ff

Tags: mathematical-economics, computation, linear-algebra

The optimal linear regulator problem according to Hansen/Sargent, 2014, Recursive models of dynamic linear economies, on page 34 ff. is stated as follows:

$-E\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\beta^t[x_t' R x_t+u_t'Qu_t+2u_t'Wx_t],\; 0<\beta<1$

subject to

$x_{t+1}=Ax_t+Bu_t+Cw_{t+1},t\geq 0$

$\{x_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ are state variables,
$\{u_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ are control variables, and
$\{w_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ are stochastic innovations into the system.

The Bellman equation is

$V(x_t)=\text{max}_{u_t}\{-(x_t' R x_t+u_t'Qu_t+2u_t'Wx_t)+\beta E_tV(x_{t+1})\}$

In the text on page 35 we have as a solution

$V(x_t)=-x_t'Px_t-\rho$

with the following expressions after using an iteration model

$P=R+\beta A'PA-(\beta A'PB+W)(Q+\beta B'PB)^{-1}(\beta B'PA+W')$

and

$\rho=\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}\text{trace}\{PCC'\}$

I am looking for an explanation how to derive $V,P,\rho$. Also the decision rule for the control variable

$u_t=-(Q+\beta B'PB)^{-1}(\beta B'PA+W')x_t$

is of interest and requires clarification.